# How to set and read cookies JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm trying to make a popup that appears on my site the first time you visit it. But not any other time after that.  So I'm trying to make it with cookies. But I'm having absolutely no luck.

I've tried following W3 school's tutorial but I haven't gotten anywhere.
What I'm doing is when the user closes the dialog, it sets a cookie.  And I'm trying to make it so when you come back, the pop up doesn't appear because the cookie is set.

Here's my code.

---

```js
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i].trim();
    if (c.indexOf(name)==0) 
      return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
  }  
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var username=getCookie("username");
  if (username!="") {
    $('#firsttimee').css({display : 'none'});
  } else {
    if (username=="" || username==null) {
      $('#firsttimee').css({display : 'block'});
    }
  }
}
        
function closepop(){
  $('#firsttimee').css({display : 'none'});
  var username = 'seen';
  setCookie("username",username,365);      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firsttimee">
  <div id="firsttimetxt">
    <center>
      <a href="http://blah.com/" id="bottomex">Click here</a>.<br><br>
      <a href="javascript:closepop()" id="bottomex">Done</a>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance! :)
[Here is a jsfidddle of my current work, for some reason when you click done the popup doesn't go away..](http://jsfiddle.net/Fzp6A/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the cookie script from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), not W3Schools, looks like W3Schools is not setting the path.

```
var docCookies = {
  getItem: function (sKey) {
    return decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null;
  },
  setItem: function (sKey, sValue, vEnd, sPath, sDomain, bSecure) {
    if (!sKey || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(sKey)) { return false; }
    var sExpires = "";
    if (vEnd) {
      switch (vEnd.constructor) {
        case Number:
          sExpires = vEnd === Infinity ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case String:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd;
          break;
        case Date:
          sExpires = "; expires=" + vEnd.toUTCString();
          break;
      }
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(sValue) + sExpires + (sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + (sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "") + (bSecure ? "; secure" : "");
    return true;
  },
  removeItem: function (sKey, sPath, sDomain) {
    if (!sKey || !this.hasItem(sKey)) { return false; }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(sKey) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + ( sDomain ? "; domain=" + sDomain : "") + ( sPath ? "; path=" + sPath : "");
    return true;
  },
  hasItem: function (sKey) {
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
  },
  keys: /* optional method: you can safely remove it! */ function () {
    var aKeys = document.cookie.replace(/((?:^|\s*;)[^\=]+)(?=;|$)|^\s*|\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?(?:\1|$)/g, "").split(/\s*(?:\=[^;]*)?;\s*/);
    for (var nIdx = 0; nIdx < aKeys.length; nIdx++) { aKeys[nIdx] = decodeURIComponent(aKeys[nIdx]); }
    return aKeys;
  }
};
```

and to set the cookie

```
docCookies.setItem("username",username,"Infinity");
```

and to get the cookie

```
docCookies.getItem("username")  //returns the string
```

or

```
docCookies.has("username")  //return boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use below code for that:

```
function getCookie(cookieName) {
    var i, x, y, cookiesArray = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < cookiesArray.length; i++) {
        x = cookiesArray[i].substr(0, cookiesArray[i].indexOf("="));
        y = cookiesArray[i].substr(cookiesArray[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == cookieName) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function checkCookie() {
    hideCookieDiv();
    var myCookie = getCookie("yourcookiename");
    if (myCookie == null || myCookie != "true") {
        showCookieDiv();
        setCookie();
    }
}

function hideCookieDiv() {
    document.getElementById('YourDivId').style.display = "none";
}

function showCookieDiv() {
    document.getElementById('YourDivId').style.display = "block";
}

function setCookie() {
    var expirationDate = new Date();
    expirationDate.setDate(expirationDate.getDate() + 365);
    document.cookie = "yourcookiename=true; expires=" + expirationDate.toUTCString();
}
```